# iOS 7 keeps sending IDLE command on empty dictionary

Tags: c#, ios, ios7, mdm

In iOS 7 Mobile Device Management, According to the documentation dated 6th July 2013, to indicate that you have no more commands, you send an empty dictionary with a 200 OK status code. However, when I do this, the device keeps sending 'Idle' commands back indefinitely. The only way to solve this was to send a 500 error code, but I don't find this clean at all. Can someone please help? Perhaps they came across the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem in IOS7 you should send response to device with 200 status and **empty body not empty dict or json** (response body must be zero bytes).

In IOS6, you should send empty dict like you said.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should send reply with empty body (vs empty dictionary)